# Regex - How to extract just the first set of floating numbers from a string - R

Tags: r, string, url

Data: `https://pastebin.com/nRsL17BD`

My strings look like this: `Bipolar 1.389 / Unipolar 6.072 / LAT -17.0`

I just need the first set of numbers right after "Bipolar". In this case, I just need `1.389`.

A `tidyverse` answer would be nice but not necessary. Thank you for the help!

Comment: It's a good idea to show what you've tried so far. You might even answer your own question in the process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This oughta do it:

```
test <- "Bipolar 1.389 / Unipolar 6.072 / LAT -17.0"
stringr::str_extract(test, "[0-9].[0-9]+")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x <- c("Bipolar 1.389 / Unipolar 6.072 / LAT -17.0", 
       "Bipolar 0.969 / Unipolar 3.678 / LAT -16.0", 
       "Bipolar 0.57 / Unipolar 3.249 / LAT 2.0", 
       "Bipolar 1.011 / Unipolar 3.345 / LAT -11.0", 
       "Bipolar 0.357 / Unipolar 3.573 / LAT -17.0", 
       "Bipolar 1.116 / Unipolar 5.934 / LAT -17.0")
```

Couple of options -

1 . Extract the first number in the string -

```
readr::parse_number(x)
#[1] 1.389 0.969 0.570 1.011 0.357 1.116
```

2. Base R way to extract the number that comes after "Bipolar"

```
as.numeric(sub('Bipolar (\\d+\\.\\d+).*', '\\1', x))
#[1] 1.389 0.969 0.570 1.011 0.357 1.116
```